# как вывести доступное место на жестком диске

Tags: linux, bash, hdd

На одном жестком диске установлены Win10 и linux
нужно узнать сколько осталось всего доступного места? вывод требуется в "одну строку" типа - 100gb 
и еще вопрос - как узнать сколько "смонтировано в корневую директорию / -"? куда смотреть? вывод такой же
главное без заморочек всяких

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Смотрим доступные разделы

```
~# lsblk
```

Смотрим точки монтирования

```
~# mount
```

Проверяем все разделы на количество использованного места

```
~# df -h
```

Смотрим типы фс и размеры партиций

```
~# fdisk -l
```

Предположим, у вас Win на разделе /dev/sdb1, смотрим сколько там места после монтирования

```
~# mkdir /mnt/ntfs && mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdb1 /mnt/ntfs && df -h /mnt/ntfs
```

Вывод всех команд легко фильтровать до "одной строчки" если вы знаете какой раздел вам нужен - grep/sed/awk

Comment: Не стоит рекомендовать `grep` там, где он излишен. Многие из приведенных комманд понимают в качестве параметра раздел.